# showing limit of integral independent of sequence chosen to approximate

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If $f_n$ is a sequence of simple functions converging to $f$ uniformly, then $a_n=\int f_n d P$ is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers and therefore has a limit $a$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. The integral $\int f d P$ of $f$ is defined to be this limit $a$. How to show that $a$ depends only on $f$ and not on the sequence $f_n$ chosen to approximate $f$. ( Here, P is the probability measure)

Answer (score 0):

If $g_n$ is another  sequence of simple functions converging to $f$ uniformly, then $|g_n(\omega)-f_n (\omega)| \leq |g_n(\omega)-f(\omega)|+|f(\omega)-f_n(\omega)|<\epsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large (independent of ($\omega$)).  So $|\int f_ndP-\int g_ndP|<\epsilon$ for such $n$. Can you finish the proof now?